# Match only whitespaces inside {}

Tags: regex

Assuming I've been given the following string to match against:

```
#sidebar h1 ul li{ #a:hover; height : 100px ;color: #fffff ; font-family: @fonts; }
```

What I want is to only match whitespaces within the curly braces { } that are not enclosed on both sides by words.

My current regex looks like this:

```
( (?!\w)|(?<!\w) )
```

But it matches characters outside the braces too. I tried look-around, but it's not really working out the way I imagined it and I just suck at regex..

I want to strip all whitespaces from css classes content so the string would be condensed to:

```
#sidebar h1 ul li{#a:hover;height:100px;color:#fffff;font-family:@fonts;}
```

Btw, I'm using the .NET Regex engine, so if anyone needs a quick testing environment for that, I found this Silverlight one pretty handy: http://www.regexlib.com/RESilverlight.aspx

Comment: Does your CSS contain any nested bracket pairs, like in `@media` sections? If it does, you won't be able to do this with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?:\B\s+|\s+\B)(?=[^{}]*\})", "")
```

But this can be fooled if there are rules inside @media sections (ie, nested braces), or voice rules that use braces as metacharacters.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to work, but since I also want to support @media sections I'll have to look into a solution without regex

Answer (score 2):

Given that some CSS elements have multi-word values (`border: 1px solid red`) the whitespace removal process you describe would be disastrous. I would recommend that you just remove whitespace in the following places:

- After '{'
- Before '}'
- Before and after ';'
- Before and after ':'

Luckily, because of the syntax of CSS, none of these patterns will occur outside the `{...}` sections. Unfortunately, I do not know the specifics of .NET regex engine, maybe this will work:

```
( +(?=[};:])|(?<=[{;:]) +)
```